# Validación con Timepicker no funciona

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validación, datetime

Tengo un formulario hecho con MVC, usando Data Annotations y timepicker para ingresar una hora. La validación de la hora funciona mal, al enviar los datos me dice "El campo Horario debe ser una fecha", como lo soluciono? Si le cambio algo, no se despiega el timepicker

Controlador:

```
namespace TimePicker.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Home
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

Modelo:

```
namespace TimePicker.Models
{
    public class Hora
    {
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]        
    public TimeSpan Horario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Horario.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.horario').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
        interval: 60,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '6:00pm',
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
});
```

Vista:

```
@model TimePicker.Models.Hora

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Hora</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Horario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Horario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control horario"" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Horario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/Horario.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: y el error que te sale??? e imprime la variable a ver que te arroja.

Comment: no me muestra el calendario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> si estoy en lo correcto supongo estas usando la librería para el
>   timepicker de jonthornton
>   (https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker), por lo que mi
>   contribución estará basada en sobre este componente:

Aquí hay varios puntos a comentar antes de analizar el problema de fondo:

-En tu TextBox para el Horario, no es necesario pongas el 'htmlAttributes', con solo el parámetro de 'class' basta

-Para que se aplique el timepicker, necesitas asignar las clases: time ui-timepicker-input

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Horario, new { @class = "form-control horario time ui-timepicker-input" } )
```

-según la documentación de jonthornton, el timeFormat en tu js, debería de ser 'h:i A'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.horario').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:i A',
        interval: 60,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '6:00pm',
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
});
```

Ahora, pasemos a lo más interesante del asunto:

-Para hacer una validación, principalmente del lado del cliente, te suguiero uses mejor una validación por expresión regular (RegularExpression). Incluso con este método, puedes validar tu rango de horarios, que el componente javascript en realidad no ejecuta si editas el valor manualmente (aunque si ssería usando una expresión regular algo complicada).

-La estrcutura TimeSpan es a mi parecer una estrcutura complicada, especialmente porque solo acepta valores del tipo 24horas.

-Mi recomendación es que utilices un tipo de dato string donde almacenarías el horario, y como lo sugiero antes hagas la validación por expresión regular.

-Si aún así, por tus requererimientos especial, todavía necesitas una propiedad que sea de tipo TimeSpan, te recomiendo crees una seguna propiedad que lea el valor de la propiedad string y la convierta a TimeSpan.

Basado en lo anterior, aquí mi sugerencia completa de solución a tu disyuntiva:

Modelo (Hora.cs)

```
public class Hora
{
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [AP]M$", ErrorMessage = "Se debe seleccionar un horario válido")]
    public string Horario { get; set; }

    //Propiedad opcional
    public TimeSpan _horario
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Horario);
                return dt.TimeOfDay;
            }
            catch
            {
                return new TimeSpan();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Vista (Index.cshtml)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Horario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Horario, new { @class = "form-control horario time ui-timepicker-input" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Horario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (Horario.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.horario').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:i A',
        interval: 60,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '6:00pm',
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas diciendo que tu parámetro Horario es de tipo DateTime por lo que tu aplicación espera una entrada de tipo fecha, si lo que quieres es recoger solo una hora debes cambiar tu modelo.

```
 public class Hora
{
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TimeSpan Horario { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Le cambio el tipo de dato, pero sigue sin mostrar el calendario

Comment: ah ya ahora lo que te faltaria es cambiar el Helper EditorFor por TextBox

Comment: le agrego eso y me sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: inspecciono el elemento y no tengo errores de javascript

Comment: asignale un id o una clase al input Horario algo así como  new { @class = "form-control horario" } y en tu script pones  $('.horario').timepicker({

Comment: edite la pregunta, le puse todo lo que me dijiste, pero no se soluciona